# VSC treats all .sql file as mssql not mysql

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-code

I have to develop my database tables inside .sql files in my project. I use MySQL and My problem is with VSC treating all the .sql files as mssql and not MySQL and detecting syntax errors which are not. I don't see mssql extension to disable, but i have MySQL syntax extension installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can setup your file associated language by clicking the current language in the bottom right:

[image]

And then configure file association by file extension:

[image]

Select MySQL

[image]

That should produce this field in your settings:

```
"files.associations": {
    "*.sql": "sql"
}
```